# Is there easy way to use a unknown character as the input for " sim.Keyboard.KeyPress"?

Tags: c#

So I have a string that I have converted into a char array and I want each of the characters to go through a loop and output in the form of a key simulation

Tried doing the logical thing such as

```
sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_{ch});
```

tried all other brackets and speechmarkings etc:

```
        string sentence = "Mahesh Chand is a cool guy ";
        char[] charArr = sentence.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char ch in charArr)
        {
            InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();

            Console.WriteLine(ch);
            sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_C);
```

btw need 
namespace "Simulating_Keypressing" at the top where the libraries are stated

Should loop through each character and output it as a simulated keypress 
thankyou

Comment: That's not logical, try sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(ch) to see if that gets you ahead.  Do make sure that "A" vs "a" is reproduced correctly, tricky because it requires simulating the Shift key and not all libraries get that right.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate entering Text use: `TextEntry()` instead of `KeyPress()` like:

```
InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();
foreach (char ch in charArr)
{
     sim.Keyboard.TextEntry(ch);
}
```

There is a very nice example in [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/520/simulating-keypress-in-the-right-way-using-inputsimulator-with-csharp-in-winforms).